# How to resize a window embedded in a composite control

Tags: c++, window, activex

### Background

I have created a composite control which is used to insert other ActiveX control programmatically. (It's a "wrapper" of other ActiveX control)

I followed steps from this guide: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218442.

Composite control will contains a "window" which contains the ActiveX control.

### Task

I need to manage the size of the window which is in the wrapper programmatically.
The idea is that if I know the size of the wrapper, I'll be able to manage the size of the window as well. (for example, wrapper's height - 10)
As I know how to do that so far are:

1. Use this function: IOleObject::GetExtent() to get the wrapper size
2. Calculate the size of the window (using the value from step 1) and pass to the Create() function.

The problem is that to create the window, I have to specify the size of the control "in client coordinates". But it seems the output from step 1 is not appropriate to the step 2.

### Question

How can I convert the output from step 1 to be an appropriate input of step 2?
Or are there any other way to specify the size of the window in the composite control programmatically?

Here is my simple code :

```
// Register the AtlAxWin class which implements ATL containment
// This is not needed for an ATL composite control
AtlAxWinInit();

// m_sizeExtent.cx and m_sizeExtent.cy is an output from step 1
RECT l_rect = {0, 0, m_sizeExtent.cx, m_sizeExtent.cy};

// m_hWnd is the composite control handle
// l_rect is the size of ActiveX control in client coordinates
CAxWindow l_hostedWnd;
l_hostedWnd.Create(m_hWnd,
                   l_rect,
                   _T("MetaStock.Chart.2"),
                   WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                   0,
                   0U);
```

Comment: You may need to handle the WM_SIZE message inside your wrapper, which usually will be sent immediately after the creation, before the window being shown. Resize all embedded windows objects inside this handler instead because in this way, when the host program is being resized, your wrapper can response automatically.